# How does F# async or C# async/await really work

Tags: c#, .net, f#, async-await

How does F#'s `async` or C#'s `async/await` keywords actually work?

Let's use the MailboxProcessor as an example:

```ml
type Agent<'T> = MailboxProcessor<'T>
let agent = Agent.Start(fun inbox ->
    let rec loop() = async {
        let! msg = inbox.Receive()
        // do something with each message as it arrives
    }
```

Based on my understanding of the F# Async pattern I know that the `let!` keyword will block the execution of the code inside the async workflow at this line until an item becomes available inside the inbox.

I'm also aware that this "blocking" is done without really blocking a thread at all.

The exact same thing applies here when looking at the new `async/await` pattern in C#. When I use the `await` keyword inside of an async method execution of the method is free to "block" at that line and leave the method call only to "wake up" and finish work at some later date when the underlying awaited task completes.

What I would like is an 'executive summary' of how F#/C# manage to 'wait without blocking'.

Comment: That's probably 4 questions?  You'll have better luck splitting them into their own questions.

Comment: VIA CLR, the language is irrelevant.

Comment: SO isn't really for "Explain this entire concept to me" questions.  It's for much more specific questions.  You're better off just picking up a book on the subject, or looking through some of the many articles/tutorials/blogs/etc. on this subject.

Comment: @Servy I understand the concept already, and have been able to use it quite effectively. I am seeking to understand how it is actually implemented. I don't think that is outside the scope of SO

Comment: The problem is that as your question is written, it basically takes a course on operating system architecture to truly answer the question.

Comment: @JesseCarter Explaining how it is implemented is something that you can (and people actually have) written entire books on.  That most certainly is well beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Comment: There has got to be someone out there who can write a paragraph or two to "explain me like I've 5", as people say on Reddit. I imagine there has to be some aspect of callbacks involved I'm just seeking some clarity as to how they're managed.

Comment: You might want to look up a video by Anders Heilsberg on the subject, there are several on Channel 9.

Comment: As the compiler platform is now open source, you can check its source code directly, http://roslyn.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JesseCarter A simple search for "async await video anders" returned a very good video as the first result: http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Anders-Hejlsberg-Introducing-Async

Comment: @JesseCarter Get a Pluralsight subscription and watch Asynchronous C# 5.0 by Jon Skeet http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/skeet-async I've watched it on TekPub and it's a brain melting in depth overview.

Comment: If you're interested in debating whether or not this question should be on Stack Overflow, [we now have our own meta to figure that out on!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).